# Take % out of an SQL column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to convert `60% -> 60` of all the columns in a table. I have tried this, but it does not work because *%* is an SQL operator.

`UPDATE host_info set host_response_rate = replace(host_response_rate,'%', '');`

But I get all the values to be NULL...

I'm using postgresql

Comment: `replace('60%', '%', '')` does produce `60`, as [you can see here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8c3345dbefb7387b2d601704478d8729). What is your actual problem?

Comment: The percent sign (%) matches any string of zero or more characters. So if i write only that % it replaces the whole column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this function, this take out the last n characters of a string. if you use 1, it will take out the last digit.

```
SELECT RIGHT(host_response_rate, 1)
FROM ...
```